# Как правильно сделать рефакторинг чат бота под большие нагрузки

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, бот, рефакторинг, highload

Цель рефакторинга - сделать бота более оптимизированным. Бот для одного приложения с play market, в котором есть сообщества и чаты. `somelib` - это REST API библиотека для этого приложения. Столкнулся с проблемой большой нагрузки из-за многопоточности. Из-за незнания как работают потоки в python, сделал бота с такой структурой:

`bot.py`:

```
import somelib

client = somelib.Client()

# Авторизация
client.login(email=<email>, password=<password>)

# Авторизация в сообществе
sub_client = somelib.SubClient(comId=<comId>, profile=client.profile)

old = []

class Bot:

    def run(self, chatid, sql, db):

        commands = Commands()

        # Название чата
        title = sub_client.get_chat_thread(chatId=chatid).title

        while True:

            # Получение последних трёх сообщений в чате
            msg = sub_client.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatid, size=3)

            # Получение сообщения, айди сообщения, тип сообщения, ник автора, айди автора
            for message, messageId, messageType, author, authorid in zip(msg.content, msg.messageId, msg.type, msg.author, msg.author.userId):

                if messageId in old:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(f"{title} | {author} : {message}")
                    if messageType == 0 and message[0] == "!":

                        if message.lower() == "!help":
                            commands.help(chatid)

                        if message.lower() == "!flip":
                            commands.flip(chatid)

                        if message.lower() == "!top":
                            commands.top(chatid, sql)

                        if message.lower() == "!stats":
                            commands.stats(authorid, author, chatid)

                    old.append(messageId)
```

`commands.py`:

```
import somelib

client = somelib.Client()

client.login(email=<email>, password=<password>)
sub_client = somelib.SubClient(comId=<comId>, profile=client.profile)

class Commands:

    def help(self, chatid):
        ...
    
    def flip(self, chatid):
        ...

    def top(self, chatid, sql):
        ...

    def stats(self, authorid, author chatid)
        ...
```

`main.py`:

```
import sqlite3
from threading import Thread

from lib.bot import Bot

db1 = sqlite3.connect("databases/chat1.db", check_same_thread=False)
sql1 = db1.cursor()
db2 = sqlite3.connect("databases/chat2.db", check_same_thread=False)
sql2 = db2.cursor()

bot = Bot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("START")
    t1 = Thread(target=bot.run, args=("aa1b9614-61df-4d3a-ac4b-a105ee75283c", sql1, db1))
    t2 = Thread(target=bot.run, args=("a5dd10aa-551d-41b9-95f6-96fd3bf087dc", sql2, db2))
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

В `main.py` у меня на данный момент 40 потоков, каждый из которых следит за отдельным чатом, и нагрузка на процессор в виртуальной машине 80-90%. Как сделать иначе? Или порекомендуйте статью где можно посмотреть про правильный подход к созданию ботов.

Comment: А есть какие-то задержки в потоке в `while True` через `time.sleep`? Если нет, то это создает ненужную нагрузку из-за частой итерации. Кроме того, есть вопрос про саму архитектуру бота. Этот бот для клиента телеграмма, и я думаю, что в API для клиентов телеграмма есть методы получения информации по изменениям в чате, я бы посмотрел в сторону `telethon`, наверняка через него можно проще. Насчет базы данных sqlite3... можно сделать одну и для многопоточной архитектуры, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/a05ec00e80ea548a27a243c9f090ecfe79c3008e/db.py#L41

Comment: Это бот не для телеграмм, и time.sleep в коде нигде нет. По поводу получения изменений в чате, есть вебсокет который за это отвечает, но он часто пропускает новые сообщения, судя по всему не успевая их обрабатывать, или я просто неправильно его использовал...

Comment: Ошибся, в последнее время много вопросов по телеграмму :) Мне кажется, что создание отдельного потока на каждый чат жирно, оно не будет эффективно работать. Думаю, лучше рассматривать вариант пула потоков. И отказаться от сокетов (используется ведь TCP) в пользу http (тот же TCP, но более удобный). Т.е. по факту достаточно одного потока на сервере для получения запросов и пула потоков для обработки запроса и отправки ответа. Клиенты с своей стороны запрашивают новые сообщения, а сервер вытаскивает их из базы. Сообщения можно возвращать от указанного от клиента timestamp сообщения + по chat_id

Comment: @gil9red можно пример?

Comment: Пример пула потоков можно тут посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/a/11529742/5909792, оно через `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` реализуется. http сервер можно сделать из коробки через класс ThreadingHTTPServer, но, думаю, удобнее будет через flask

Comment: @gil9red не совсем понимаю зачем тут сервер. Какую задачу он будет выполнять?

Comment: Получение запросов от клиентов, обработку и возврат результата

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выглядит, что класс `Bot` взял на себя больше отвественности чем нужно. Я бы вынес в отдельную часть обязаность опрашивать чаты и детектить там команды, после чего ставил бы их в очередь, а бот бы из очереди просто читал. Возможно отправлял в асинхрон на исполнение воркерам. Ниже попытался оформить идею в виде схемки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Преимущества такого решения, что мы можем независимо оптимизировать или масштабировать эти две части. Всегда выгодно разделять вещи которые требует оперативного ответа и имеют высокую нагрузку через очередь от вещей которые могут быть в фоне выполнены без жестких регламентов по времени и по окончанию оповестить о результате в нужный чат.

В идеале конечно подписаться бы на оповещение о новых сообщениях, чтобы не ддосить приложение, а получать и обрабатывать их по необходимости. Тогда вообще система становится пассивная. Если нет новых сообщений, то ни чего не грузится.

***PS***. я лично ботов не писал, так что смотрите на это с некоторой долей скептицизма